# I need some code to animate my sprite

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite

I've tried a bunch of different things and nothing seems to work so I am hoping someone here has some free time and wants to help out. I am trying to create javascript for an animation of a sprite strip that has 11 images stacked vertically with each frame being 640 x 889. I want the animation to start when the window opens and run through the frames back and forth 3 times and then stop. There are 11 frames the sequence should go 1....11 then 11...1, three times and take a total of 3 seconds to complete the three loops. Thanks in advance for the help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <meta name ="viewport" content = "width=640, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"/>
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bmw-glow">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var fps          = 11,
    currentFrame = 0,
    totalFrames  = 11,
    elem         = document.getElementById("bmw-glow"),
    currentTime  = new Date().getTime();

(function animloop(time){
  var delta = (time - currentTime) / 1000;

  currentFrame += (delta * fps);

  var frameNum = Math.floor(currentFrame);

  if (frameNum >= totalFrames) {
    currentFrame = frameNum = 0;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animloop);

  elem.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + (frameNum * 889) + "px";

  currentTime = time;
})(currentTime);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#bmw-glow {
  width: 640px;
  height: 889px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: url("images/Social/Social_6_S.jpg");
}
```

Comment: what does not work? what are the symptoms? add a jsfiddle link to the post.

Comment: It just seems to display the first frame and doesnt animate anything. when working right the bmw should have a yellow glow around it. http://jsfiddle.net/xtQDn/1/

Comment: Have you checked the console? Getting any errors?

Comment: @Eric_S: Do you have the image somewhere that isn't password protected? Because I can't see it on your fiddle as it is.

Comment: @Shmiddty ahh, still new and forgot that step, heres the error i got [14:15:34.370] ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:44

Comment: @MattBurland i uploaded it to http://i45.tinypic.com/4qj0b5.jpg thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Matt's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/xtQDn/5/

First, you need to "mask" the animation so that you can only see one frame at a time. To do this, simply set the container's width and height to the size of one frame:

```
#bmw-glow {
  width: 104px;
  height: 144.45px; /* Fractional pixels are not good. */
  margin: 0px;
  background: url("http://i45.tinypic.com/4qj0b5.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

Second, I modified the code that gives us the current frame to be an absolute sine wave. This gives us a little bit of easing, which may not be desired for all cases, but I think is fine for this case.

```
var freq     = 1,  //frequency of the animation. Roughly how many times per second it should loop. Higher number is faster, lower number is slower.
currentFrame = 0,
totalFrames  = 11,
deltaFrame   = 1,
frameStep    = 1589 / totalFrames,
elem         = document.getElementById("bmw-glow"),
currentTime  = new Date().getTime();

(function animloop(time){
  var delta = (time - currentTime) / 1000;

  currentFrame += (delta);

  var frameNum = Math.floor(Math.abs(Math.sin(currentFrame*freq) * totalFrames));

  requestAnimFrame(animloop);

  elem.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + (frameNum * frameStep) + "px";

  currentTime = time;
})(currentTime);
```

Obviously in this example, there is some jittering because we are dealing with fractional pixels. I believe the image you uploaded to tinypic was scaled down, which is why this is occurring.

Comment: Thanks, this is highly appreciated. I actually ended up solving my issue by creating two images, one for the background and one for the glow and i used jQuery's .fadeToggle to animate the fade effect.

Comment: what should I do to jump to first step instead of playing backwards ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that requestAnimationFrame is not defined. It's not implemented by all browsers.

I found a shim [here](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

```
    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

and updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtQDn/3/)

Now it does something, but I don't think it's exactly what you had in mind!

Comment: nah it doesnt, the frames have rising degrees of glow around the bmw and i want to animate it so it looks like a flowing glow going on and off. thanks for the help though.